# Got 200 on an URL that should gives a 404

Tags: .htaccess, grav

I just passed my website made with Grav on the [Spaghetti scanner](https://github.com/m4ll0k/Spaghetti).

It listed a lot of *common used files and folders*. I tried many of those knowing those files and folders didn't exist at all on my webserver.

Every links (like https://example.com/node.xml.zip) give a HTTP 200 with my homepage displayed ; it should be a 404.

It can be a SEO disaster and a pain in the 4ss to discover real vulnerabilities with a scanner…

I'm using the default `.htaccess` file, directly on a domain name.

Am I missing something ?

Regards

Comment: Interesting. I can replicate this on my install as well. I would classify that as a bug, personally.

Comment: Issue opened: https://github.com/getgrav/grav/issues/1713

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this is indeed an error with Grav. I opened an [issue](https://github.com/getgrav/grav/issues/1713) on Github and the bug has already been patched.

You should see a fix for this behavior in the next release.

**Update:**
As of the 1.3.8 release (October 27th, 2017), this bug fix has been officially released.